# How to make two alerts trigger together with the Pivot Reversal Strategy?

Tags: tradingview-api

I'm trying to edit this Pivot Reversal Strategy so that there is two alerts every time there is a long or short order. The first alert is triggered by the strategy.order() function and works fine, but the second alert using the alert() function seems to trigger on every bar close:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Pivot Reversal Strategy", overlay=true)
leftBars = input(4)
rightBars = input(2)
swh = pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)
swl = pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)
swh_cond = not na(swh)
hprice = 0.0
hprice := swh_cond ? swh : hprice[1]
le = false
le := swh_cond ? true : (le[1] and high > hprice ? false : le[1])
if (le)
    strategy.entry("PivRevLE", strategy.long, comment="PivRevLE", stop=hprice + syminfo.mintick, alert_message = "stop short bot")
    alert("start long bot",alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
swl_cond = not na(swl)
lprice = 0.0
lprice := swl_cond ? swl : lprice[1]
se = false
se := swl_cond ? true : (se[1] and low < lprice ? false : se[1])
if (se)
    strategy.entry("PivRevSE", strategy.short, comment="PivRevSE", stop=lprice - syminfo.mintick, alert_message="stop long bot")
    alert("start short bot",alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

How do I fix this? I think I need to make the stop loss parameter part of the if condition but how?